# how to load view in codeigniter with variable?

Tags: php, codeigniter

hi i want to just load the view page using variable not by direct name

here is my code:-

```
function load_views()
    {
      $this->load->model('test_model');
      $data=$this->test_model->getMenu();
      foreach($data as $data_menu) {
            echo $data_menu->views;
            $this->load->view($data_menu->views);
      }
    }
```

output :

```
test_view
  An Error Was Encountered Unable to load the requested file: .php
```

actually it takes the value from db but it did not call the view file which is present in the view folder.

this is my view page :

```
    <div class="panel-heading">
           <h3 class="panel-title">Dashboard</h3>
    </div>
    <br/>
        <div class="row">


            <?php
                $count = 0;
                 foreach($m as $data_menu){

                    if(($count% 4== 0))
                    {
            ?>      
                        <div class = "row"></div>
            <?php
                    }
            ?>
                 <div class="col-md-3"> 
                    <!--<a href="<?/*php echo base_url()*/?>index.php/<?php/* echo $data_menu->views*/?>">-->

                    <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/dn_login_controller/load_views">

                        <img class="img-rounded" src="" height="80" width="80" />
                         <div class="caption"> 
                            <h3><?php echo $data_menu->function_name; ?></h3>
                        </div>
                    </a>

                 </div>

            <?php
                    $count++;
                 }
            ?>


      </div>  
</div>
```

Now in the view i want load views dynamically but i cant...
please help me.....

Comment: could you do a `var_dump($data_menu->views)` instead of an echo?

Comment: check before loading view `if($data_menu->views!='')`

Comment: Does this work: `$this->load->view('test_view');` ? (do you have a view with that name?)

Comment: do you have a test_view file in view folder or first check statically test_view to load

Comment: @azeós  it only print the name of view it wont redirect  it

Comment: yes i have checked with original file

Comment: $this->load->view('test_view'); this work  but i want it accessing by variables ....

Answer (score 0):

If you `var_dump($data)` you will see that it has an empty value somewhere in the array.

As kumar_v said in a comment, try to check for empty values

```
foreach($data as $data_menu) {
    if(!empty(trim($data_menu->views)))
        $this->load->view($data_menu->views);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This issue might be because, you cannot just directly load multiple views from single function/controller, when you just load view CI will send it to browser.
There are two other workaround for this :

- Pass 2nd parameter NULL & 3rd parameter TRUE while loading your menu views, which will create your html as data instead of sending it to browser. Refer this link : [codeigniter: loading multiple views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775869/codeigniter-loading-multiple-views)
- Create a view file, pass your data to that view & on that view execute for loop & load all your views.

Comment: Of course you can load multiple views from a same controller. Load->view acts as an include()++

Comment: Yes I changed my answer, please refer the link I mentioned in it.

Comment: The TRUE value is only needed if you want to retrieve the load->view as a variable then manipulate this variable. If you just want to load a header, main_content, footer, you don't need to set TRUE. Just call the 3 load->views and that's it. Be more precise in your answer, it is misleading.